# How to fetch container element based on class name and outer element's ID using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

In below stuff, i want to apply - display `none` style on element `strong`.
How can i find element `strong` based on li's id and apply css ?

```
<li id="rowForcustomfield_11300" class="item">
  <div class="wrap">
    <strong title="REVENUE NET" class="name">REVENUE NET:</strong>
    <div id="customfield_11300-val" class="value type-cascading-summary-field editable-field inactive"     data-fieldtype="cascading-summary-field" data-fieldtypecompletekey="com.crawco.plugins.jira.company-   jira-customfields:cascading-summary-field" title="Click to edit">
   </div>
</li>
```

so, need something like as below: (to search `name` class element inside list's reference ID)

```
$("#rowForcustomfield_11300 name")
```

How can we do achieve this using jQuery.

NOTE: In complete HTML of above stuff, there are many list element and each one contain single '' element which needs to find apply css.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to find out an element with the specified class

```
$("#rowForcustomfield_11300 .name")
```

Comment: @Cherniv Ohh... I was still editing it, removing the second option

Comment: Anyway , you're the winner!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/8hPMx/)**

```
//apply style display 'none' 
$('#rowForcustomfield_11300 strong').hide();

//OR

//clear content
$('#rowForcustomfield_11300 strong').html(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var li_id ="rowForcustomfield_11300"
$("li#"+li_id ).find(".name").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using invalid syntax in your selector. It must be 
`$("#rowForcustomfield_11300 .name")`. remember add a `dot(.)` before a class name